# C# MVC After I login, i dont get the option to Logout

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am doing my first MVC web app. Im starting with the Login, logout and registration. The registration works great by creating a new user and adding a record to my a table in the database. I am also able to login. the issue i am having is after i login i get redirected to my homepage like it suppose to, but i am not given the option to logout. im my _layout i have an if/else statement that suppose to check if request is authenticated then give the option to logout but is does not.

I am fairly new to this and any help would be appreciated. I am providing the code i have so far.

This is what i have in my UserController: functions and methods for index page and login, logout, register and isvalid

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    private GroceryListEntities db = new GroceryListEntities();

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LogIn()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogIn(User u)
    {

        if (IsValid(u.UserName, u.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(u.UserName, false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login details are wrong.");
        }
        return View(u);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(User U)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (db)
            {
                //you should check duplicate registration here 
                db.Users.Add(U);
                db.SaveChanges();
                ModelState.Clear();
                U = null;
                ViewBag.Message = "Successfully Registration Done";
                //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        return View(U);
    }

    public ActionResult LogOut()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    private bool IsValid(string userName, string password)
    {
        bool IsValid = false;

        using (var db = new sogeti.got.groceries.app.Models.GroceryListEntities())

        {
            var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName);

            if (user != null)
            {
                if (user.Password == password)
                {
                    IsValid = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return IsValid;
    }

    // GET: Users
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Users.ToList());
    }
```

Login view:

```
@model project.app.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<h2>Login</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login Failed, check details");
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login Form</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(u => u.UserName)</div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(u => u.Password)</div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Password)
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
    </fieldset>
</div>
}

@* This below line is for create javascript section *@

@section Scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Registration view:

```
@model project.Models.User

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>Register</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Registration Failed");

<fieldset>
    <legend>Registration Form</legend>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <div style="border:solid 1px green">
            @ViewBag.Message
        </div>
    }
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")</div>
```

in my _layout i have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:auto; background-color:aqua">
    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <strong>@Html.Encode(User.Identity.Name)</strong>
        @Html.ActionLink("LogOut", "LogOut", "Users")
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Registration", "Register", "Users")
        <span> | </span>
        @Html.ActionLink("Login", "LogIn", "Users")
    }
  </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - <i>Got Groeries</i> </p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add you Web.Config file to your question.

Comment: Instead of `Request.IsAuthenticated`, try `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is to add the following lines in the modules seccion, in the system.webServer tag (this should be inside your Web.config file)

```
<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
<add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
```

I had the same issue, and this made the `Request.IsAuthenticated` to always be `false`.

These are the default values for [FormAuthentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx):

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"
           protection="All"
           timeout="30"
           name=".ASPXAUTH" 
           path="/"
           requireSSL="false"
           slidingExpiration="true"
           defaultUrl="default.aspx"
           cookieless="UseDeviceProfile"
           enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
  </authentication>
</system.web>
```

You don't need to have all of those properties for the forms tag, but you should have the authentication mode.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but i get the same result as before. I do not get the option to logout @cacho

Comment: did you re-build your application?